# continuous uniform distribution for multiple random variables

Tags: probability

Consider three independent uniformly distributed (taking values between 0 and 1) random variables. What is the probability that the middle of the three values (between the lowest and the highest value) lies between a and b where $0≤a<b≤1$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an order statistics question. Arrange the random variables as $$0\leq X_{(1)}\leq X_{(2)}\leq X_{(3)}\leq 1$$

Then you need to find

$$\text{Pr}[a\leq X_{(2)}\leq b]$$

Search order statistics to find this probability.